# Cordova no Visual Studio - Erro na Compilação. Não gera apk

Tags: visual-studio, apache-cordova

Estou iniciando no Cordova e decidi tentar pelo Visual Studio Community 2017, o qual instalei com sucesso, somente o Pacote de Ferramentas para Apache Cordova + SDK Android, Google Emulator. Entao, criei um projeto novo, em branco, padrao, para nnão ficar nada complicado, e tentei compilar, o que me retorna a saída abaixo, mesmo reiniciando o VS.

Essa é a tela com a configuraçao da instalaçao do VS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eis a tela com a saída (erros):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que há de errado? O que falta?

Comment: o erro é exatamente o que está escrito ali, não está encontrando o java. Veja se está instalado corretamente e se as variáveis de ambiente tbm estão, como por exemplo `PATH`

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual... perfeito! era isso! Instalei o JDK, rodei novamente e funcionou. Grato. Ah, coloca como resposta para eu marcar.

Comment: feito. já tive esse problema tb, instala muita coisa e sempre algo não funciona, ou o Java ou o CLI, ou o node....

Answer (score 1):

Como mostra a mensagem, isso acontece porque não foi encontrado o `java` ao executar algum comando.

Isso acontece com a instalação do **Apache Cordova** no **Visual Studio** porque são instaladas muitas coisas além do `java`, como o `nodejs` por exemplo.

Para confirmar se o java está instalado e devidamente adicionado à variável de ambiente `PATH` do Windows, abra uma janela de prompt de comando (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> e escreva "cmd"), e digite "javac -version".

Deve exitir a versão do `Java SDK` instalado, se não aparecer é sinal que não está instalado ou não foi instalado e configurado corretamente.

Baixe o `Java SDK` do site oficial (aqui: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), e após instalar teste novamente o comando acima, e tudo deve funcionar corretamente.